# How to extract records by comparing two different values in one column

Tags: sql

i need to check 2 or more values in one column and extract the data. It is not like using "in" operator.

Example:
i have a table to with two columns User id, Standard ID. My application send's multiple values of standard id's. Now i need to find the User who has rights for all the standards.

In the below example i need to find "UserID" who are mapped to both 529 and 551.

```
UserID     StandardId
9-              529
12-             529
12-             551
15-             529
17-             551
17-             529
18-             529
21-             529
21-             551
49-             529
58-             529
60-             529
62-             529
62-             551
64-             529
64-             551
81-             529
83-             529
83-             551
226-            551
226-            529
298-            551
298-            529
335-            529
```

Based on current mappings there are 7 standards to verified. This mappings may grow in future.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for "relational division". Which form you want depends on whether there could be other values (except 529 and 551) in the table and, if so, whether those users should be included in the result set when searching for just 529 and 551.

Answer (score 1):

I might not be completely understanding your question, but would this work?

```
SELECT UserId FROM [table] WHERE StandardId = 529
INTERSECT
SELECT UserId FROM [table] WHERE StandardId = 551
```

You can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) for more information on `INTERSECT` queries.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could group on ID and create your aggregate function to check if it matches this two values

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select t.id 
from table t 
join table t1 
on t.userid = t1.userid
where t.standardid= 529 and t1.standardid = 551
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UserId FROM [table] WHERE StandardId IN (529, 551/*you can pass in the list here*/)
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING COUNT(StandardId) > 1 /*can change to more when the list is longer*/
```